# Query returning dates in a given range

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table that looks like this:

```
PersonnelId 
AbsenceReason 
AbsenceFrom 
AbsenceTo
```

Now I would like a query that returns the following result.
I provide a daterange and for all the dates it should return whether the person is absent or not.
For example :

```
PersonnelId = 4
AbsenceReason = Holiday
AbsenceFrom = 2/12/2012
AbsenceTo = 10/12/2012
```

When I run the query I give the month of december as input.
I would like the result to display the following :

```
1/12/2012 "Available" 
2/12/2012 "Holiday" 
3/12/2012 "Holiday"
...
11/12/2012 "Available"
...
```

Comment: Agreed, http://whathaveyoutried.com?

Comment: what is the format of your date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
SQL> create table person (PersonnelId primary key, AbsenceReason , AbsenceFrom , AbsenceTo)
  2  as
  3  select 4, 'Holiday', '2/12/2012', '10/12/2012'
  4  from dual;

Table created.
```

just set the `to_date('12-2012', 'mm-yyyy')` as applicable month/year:

```
SQL> with mon as (select d
  2                 from (select to_date('12-2012', 'mm-yyyy') + rownum - 1 d
  3                         from dual
  4                       connect by level <= 31)
  5               where trunc(d, 'mm') = to_date('12-2012', 'mm-yyyy'))
  6  select personnelId, m.d,
  7         case
  8           when m.d between p.AbsenceFrom and p.AbsenceTo then 'Holiday'
  9           else 'Available'
 10         end absent
 11    from mon m
 12         cross join person p
 13   order by 1, 2;

PERSONNELID D          ABSENT
----------- ---------- ---------
          4 01/12/2012 Available
          4 02/12/2012 Holiday
          4 03/12/2012 Holiday
          4 04/12/2012 Holiday
          4 05/12/2012 Holiday
          4 06/12/2012 Holiday
          4 07/12/2012 Holiday
          4 08/12/2012 Holiday
          4 09/12/2012 Holiday
          4 10/12/2012 Holiday
          4 11/12/2012 Available
          4 12/12/2012 Available
          4 13/12/2012 Available
          4 14/12/2012 Available
          4 15/12/2012 Available
          4 16/12/2012 Available
          4 17/12/2012 Available
          4 18/12/2012 Available
          4 19/12/2012 Available
          4 20/12/2012 Available
          4 21/12/2012 Available
          4 22/12/2012 Available
          4 23/12/2012 Available
          4 24/12/2012 Available
          4 25/12/2012 Available
          4 26/12/2012 Available
          4 27/12/2012 Available
          4 28/12/2012 Available
          4 29/12/2012 Available
          4 30/12/2012 Available
          4 31/12/2012 Available
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you? Please try:

```
SELECT date_col, NVL(AbsenceReason, 'Available') AS Reason 
FROM  (SELECT To_date('01-JUN-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy') 
              + LEVEL - 1 AS date_col 
       FROM   dual 
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= To_date('06-JUL-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy') - 
                           To_date('01-JUN-2012', 'dd-mon-yyyy') + 
                                       1)d 
      left join yourtable t1 
             ON d.date_col BETWEEN t1.absencefrom AND t1.absenceto;
```

In this example `'01-JUN-2012'` is from date and `'06-JUL-2012'` is to date.